# How to properly set Enum value?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, enums

I have a Enum:

```
[DataContract(Namespace = Namespace.Default)]
public enum CancelledStatus
{
    [EnumMember]
    NotCancelled = 0,

    [EnumMember]
    CancelRequestBySystem = 1,

    [EnumMember]
    CancelRequestByUser = 2,

    [EnumMember]
    Cancelled = 3
}
```

And in several places I have second thing in classes:

```
    [DataMember]
    public virtual int CancelledStatusId { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public virtual CancelledStatus Cancelled
    {
        get
        {
            return (CancelledStatus)this.CancelledStatusId;
        }

        set
        {
            this.CancelledStatusId = (int)value;
        }
    }
```

This is done to write int value of enum in database (with nhibernate help).

```
<property name="CancelledStatusId" column="CancelledStatus"/>
```

**MY PROBLEM** is that I can write data to database, **BUT** I can't get it from there because I started to receive errors:

```
The type 'SpecialEntities.CancelledStatus' has no settable properties.
```

I can receive data from database **IF** I remove `set` from `CancelledStatus Cancelled` but if I do that, I can't write data to database.

No matter how I look at it, I cant find the reason of this issue at all, and I can't understand it (I have severan Enum for different tables and classes. They are working and they are done exactly as `CancelledStatus`).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The way I map `enum` is like this:

```
// the integer
<property name="CancelledStatusId" column="CancelledStatus"/>
// the enum
<property name="Cancelled" column="CancelledStatus" 
    type="MyNamespace.CancelledStatus, MyLib"
    insert="false" update="false"  />
```

Where the `MyNamespace` and `MyLib` should be replaced with your own... NHibernate will be able to init such property with proper `enum` value

The Enum property, could then be mapped like this:

```
[DataMember]
public virtual CancelledStatus Cancelled { get; set }
```

Becuase NHibernate will any loaded value provide with instantiated `enum`

Comment: And what it will store in database? Int value or string? Anyway... issue with The type 'SpecialEntities.CancelledStatus' has no settable properties. - still bother me a lot, cant i=understand why its appeared.

Comment: Oleg I extended my answer... we can map both 1) integer and 2) the enum. One of these values MUST be readonly.  *(it is up to you, but one msut have `insert="false" update="false" `)* This way we can get from DB *(NHibernate will do that)* both values loaded and prepared for us. Only one value is needed when we create entity *(the one which is editable by mapping)* does it help?

Comment: The moment is that I dont need to store Enum in database, and its Id is already stored as int. The problem is that for some reason int is not converted to Enum and as a result I am getting The type 'SpecialEntities.CancelledStatus' has no settable properties. (at leas as I can see). And as I told already, I have several Enum which works and looks exactly as this one, but only this gives me an Error for set property

Comment: I updated the answser, and would suggest - let that to be done by NHibernate. Do not solve that issue in C#. Just set the integer value for new entity, and for any loaded value, you will get both. BUT if you have an issue with loaded value - and **its conversion** into enum === the integer value is not realted to that enum! Check your DB. And maybe chnage your mapping - integer should be readonly and enum editable. That way you can be sure, that you've provided existing enum value... Does that help?